# Matlab: Select a variable name and find the corresponding value

Tags: matlab

Can somebody explain me how i get some  specific values after the = sign? The input File is a .subvar file format.
I dont know how to jump in the right row and column to get the value. Do you have a matlab tutorial link for such a problem.

I need for example two specific values (after the = sign):
The value of $_Wk1_lr_m and $_Wk1_voll_m

```
!file.version=1.543! 
! Testautomatisch 

subvargroup.begin ($G_Wk1)   
  subvar(      $_Wk1_lr_C_x,                                   str = ' 0.019 ' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk1_lr_m,                                     str = ' 15601 ' )               ! [kg] lr  
  subvar(      $_Wk1_lr_C_y,                                   str = '-0.007 ' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk1_lr_C_z,                                   str = ' 1.644 ' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk1_voll_m,                                   str = ' 33690 ' )               ! [kg] voll 
subvargroup.end   ($G_Wk1)
```

[image]

What are the first steps to get the right row and the right column? Thank you and stay at home :)

Comment: Your code does not look like MATLAB.  What language is it?

Answer (score 0):

read the file line by line, match the line format and extract the values using regular expression `regexp`

```
fid=fopen('mydata.subvars','rt');
res=struct;
while(~feof(fid))
  line=fgetl(fid);
  if(regexp(line,'^\s*subvar\(','once'))
     val=regexp(line,'\$_(\w+),\s*str\s*=\s*''\s*([0-9.-]+)\s*','tokens');
     if(length([val{:}])==2)
        res.(val{1}{1})=str2num(val{1}{2});
     end
  end
end
fclose(fid);
```

here is the result

```
>> res

res = 

    Wk1_lr_C_x: 0.0190
      Wk1_lr_m: 15601
    Wk1_lr_C_y: -0.0070
    Wk1_lr_C_z: 1.6440
    Wk1_voll_m: 33690
```

Comment: ok, but i get the the whole column (results) i just look for only two results 15601 and 33690.... thank you so much fo further help

Comment: then just type `res.Wk1_lr_m` and `res.Wk1_voll_m`